# node.js (socket.io) downloaded example

Tags: node.js

I downloaded code from this site http://rawkes.com/articles/creating-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-with-websockets-and-node.html (https://github.com/robhawkes/mozilla-festival) yesterday.

But if I open localhost:8000 it just writes "Welcome to socket.io." and nothing else, but it should create new player and more things... I am beginer in this so I cant find any problem..but it looks this function is not starting `function onSocketConnection(client) {}`

Comment: I noticed that the tutorial is quite old. Are you using the same versions of Node and Socket.io as the tutorial author?

Answer (score 0):

1) Run game.js inside main folder with node
2) Open the index.html file (inside public folder) with your html5 capable browser

Also you can find the developing tutorial here: http://rawkes.com/articles/creating-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-with-websockets-and-node.html